# Not displaying flat rate

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I have magento2.0.2 version,and added a flat rate of $10 per item in the backend but it doesn't show in front end

Answer (score 1):

The shipping is ONLY available for products that have weight set to Yes.

Configure it in your product details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to reindex your price index.

```
magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
```